Connection to Bluez failed Bluez daemon is not running, blueman-manager cannot continue.... Lubuntu 24.04
Tried to activate Bluetooth manager deamon with
sudo bluetoothd
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start
sudo service bluetooth start
sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service
sudo ststemctl enable bluetooth.service
No luck with this. What should I try next please?
name@name-hp350g1:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth status
[sudo] password for name:
o bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead)
Docs: man:bluetooth(8)
Sep 16 10:25:58 name-hp350g1 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service was skipped because of an unmet c...etooth).
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
name@name-hp350g1:~$
name@name-hp350g1:~$ sudo rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
name@name-hp350g1:~$
name@name-hp350g1:~$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth
[sudo] password for name:
o bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead)
Docs: man:bluetooth(8)
Sep 19 08:51:15 name-hp350g1 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service was skipped because of an unmet condition>
lines 1-6/6 (END)
iain@iain-hp350g1:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:blaze/rtbth-dkms
[sudo] password for iain:
Repository: 'Types: deb
URIs: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/blaze/rtbth-dkms/ubuntu/
Suites: noble
Components: main
'
Description:
Packages of linux bluetooth dkms driver for rt3290 chip
Source: https://github.com/loimu/rtbth-dkms
More info: https://launchpad.net/~blaze/+archive/ubuntu/rtbth-dkms
Adding repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Ign:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/blaze/rtbth-dkms/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu noble InRelease
Err:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/blaze/rtbth-dkms/ubuntu noble Release
404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::81 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/blaze/rtbth-dkms/ubuntu noble Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
iain@iain-hp350g1:~$ iain@iain-hp350g1:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Ign:2 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/blaze/rtbth-dkms/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu noble InRelease
Err:4 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/blaze/rtbth-dkms/ubuntu noble Release
404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::81 443]
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/blaze/rtbth-dkms/ubuntu noble Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
iain@iain-hp350g1:~$ sudo apt-get install rtbth-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package rtbth-dkms
iain@iain-hp350g1:~$

As the HP 350G1 laptop has a Ralink 3290 network card, do I need rtbth-dkms or should it work without?
